# Does padding a string of length 0 with the %.*s format in printf() invoke any UB? If so, which?

Tags: c

I want to be able to pad 0 or more spaces at runtime with `printf()`

The solutions I have come up with:

```
printf("%.*cord", pad_len, 'w');  
printf("%.*s", pad_len, "word");  
printf("%.*sword", pad_len, "");
```

I like the third approach best because it doesn't depend on hardcoding literals, so I would like confirmation. Specifically, whether it invokes any UB, or has any implementation-defined aspects that would affect its cross-plaform viability.

Comment: There's nothing special about zero-length strings. You can format and pad them just like any other string.

Comment: Consider that usually the string you're formatting is a variable, not a literal, and there's no requirement to check first that the string's length is non-zero.

Comment: @devgirl05,  Perhaps `char *s = some_string;  printf("%.*s%s", pad_len, "", s);` to pad arbitrary strings.  Please tell more about why you want to "pad 0 or more spaces at runtime".

Comment: `"%.*c"` is UB -- https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p4 -- *If a precision appears with any other conversion specifier, the behavior is undefined.* Same text in C23 7.23.6.1.4.

Comment: Example #1 is just silly (and invokes UB... News to me!),,, #2 and #3 will produce different output (assuming the value of `pad_len` is the same for both.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does padding a string of length 0 with the %.*s format in printf() invoke any UB?

No.  Padding a *string* of length 0 with the "%.*s" format is OK.

Of the following:
The first is UB as `"%c"` is not specified to allow a *precision*.
The other 2 are OK:

```
int pad_len = 0;
printf("%.*cord", pad_len, 'w');  // UB
printf("%.*s", pad_len, "word");  
printf("%.*sword", pad_len, "");
```

What is best (or other approaches) depends on the higher levels goals OP has yet to state.

Comment: `"%.*c"` is UB -- see C11 7.21.6.1p4 or C23 7.23.6.1p4

Comment: @pmg Right you are   Post amended.